# Why is there a problem with applying the keyboard in my kivy game?

Tags: python, kivy

I have this code which implements the usage of the keyboard in my kivy program. So I have this problem where when my game runs, everything works well but when I use my keyboard there is no response. What should I do in this case?

This code block below is the file which allows to take in user input such as left, right for moving left and right.

```
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout


def keyboard_closed(self):
    self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
    self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_up=self.on_keyboard_up)
    self._keyboard = None


def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    if keycode[1] == 'left':
        self.current_speed_x = self.speed_x
    elif keycode[1] == 'right':
        self.current_speed_x = -self.speed_x
    elif keycode[1] == ord('p'):
        self.toggle_pause()
        self.is_paused = True
    return True


def on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode):
    self.current_speed_x = 0
    return True


def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if not self.state_game_over and self.state_game_has_started:
        if touch.x < self.width / 2:
            self.current_speed_x = self.speed_x
        else:
            self.current_speed_x = -self.speed_x
    return super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)

def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    self.current_speed_x = 0
```

In my main file I have this code which connects takes in the user input from keyboard

```
if self.is_desktop():
            self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self.keyboard_closed, self)
            self._keyboard.bind(on_keyboard_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
            self._keyboard.bind(on_keyboard_up=self.on_keyboard_up)
```

I was expecting that this code would allow me to use my keyboard to accept the input and allow the user to move left and right. But it isn't working

Comment: First step in debugging is to make sure the code is actually being called.  Add a print statement (or write a short message to a temp file, or something similar) to the `on_keyboard_down()` and `on_keyboard_up()` functions, so you can at least see that they are definitely being called.